# SBT unable to resolve dependencies from different repository

Tags: scala, sbt

In my sbt project I have two internal repositories

```
resolvers += "Team 1 Releases" at "https://team1repo"
resolvers += "Team 2 Releases" at "https://team2repo"
```

I am using an artifact (lets call it ArtifactA) which is hosted on Team 1 Releases. Within it's POM (artifactA.pom) file I have the following parent:

```
<parent>
  <artifactId>ArtifactB</artifactId>
  <groupId>team2</groupId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</parent>
```

This ArtifactB is hosted on team2repo. When sbt tries to resolve ArtifactB, it tries to find it on team1repo release (where my ArtifactA is), but it doesnt try to find it on team2repo and I get this error:

```
Not Found url=https://team1repo/team2/1.2/artifactb.pom
```

It should try to find it on:

```
url=https://team2repo/team2/1.2/artifactb.pom
```

What should I do to resolve this issue? Maven can resolve this easily. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the ArtifactA and ArtifactB libraryDependency entries in youd build.sbt file?

Comment: Do you have team 2 repo mentioned in your `artifactA.pom`?

Comment: @laughedelic no. I think this is a pom pareting problem. Maven can resolve this mess but sbt. I will just not to use things like this anymore. Ty.